# How to assertRaise socket error ([Errno 111] Connection refused) in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem catching an exception in my tests. I know for a fact that the exception is raised (I can see my custom error message in Celery terminal).

> Error sending confirmation mail: [Errno 111] Connection refused

How can I catch that exception in my test?

tests.py

```
from socket import error as socket_error

def test_email_sent(self):
    """
    Checks if the email was sent.
    """
    with self.assertRaises(socket_error):
        self.newsletter.send(self.request)
```

models.py

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
    ...
    def send(self, req):  
       newsletter_mail.delay(params)
       self.save()
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
from .utils import htmlmail
from socket import error as socket_error

app = Celery('newsletter.tasks', broker='redis://localhost/')

@app.task
def newsletter_mail(title, user, ctx, template, images, ignore_result=True):
    try:
        htmlmail(title, user, ctx, template, images)
    except socket_error as serror:
        print 'Error sending confirmation mail: ' + str(serror)
```

utils.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
charset='utf-8'
smtp_server = settings.EMAIL_HOST
smtp_user = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
smtp_pass = settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD


def htmlmail(sbj,recip,msg,template='',texttemplate='',textmsg='',images=(), recip_name='',sender=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,sender_name=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_SENDER_NAME,charset=charset):
   ...

   if settings.EMAIL_BACKEND == "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend":
      smtp = SMTP()
      smtp.connect(smtp_server)
      if smtp_user: smtp.login(smtp_user, smtp_pass)
      smtp.sendmail(sender, recip, msgRoot.as_string())
      smtp.quit()
   else:
      print "Email for:", recip
      print text

def render(context,template):
   if template:
      t = loader.get_template(template)
      return t.render(Context(context))
   return context

def named(mail,name):
   if name: return '%s <%s>' % (name,mail)
   return mail
```

traceback:

```
[2015-12-04 15:10:22,970: ERROR/MainProcess] Task newsletter.tasks.newsletter_mail[a68161d1-919d-4a9f-90d5-6359d42ccb83] raised unexpected: error(111, 'Connection refused')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sasa/.virtualenvs/konceptich2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sasa/.virtualenvs/konceptich2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sasa/Projects/konceptich2/web/newsletter/tasks.py", line 10, in newsletter_mail
    htmlmail(title, user, ctx, template, images)
  File "/home/sasa/Projects/konceptich2/web/newsletter/utils.py", line 75, in htmlmail
    smtp.connect(smtp_server)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```